# Constant bugs from [NSArray count] being unsigned

Tags: objective-c, for-loop, int, nsarray

I'm creating bugs over and over by failing to notice the consequences of [NSArray count] being `unsigned`. Today's example is relatively unusual:

```
for (int i = -1; i < [myArray count]; i++) {
```

This loop never executes! You need `(int)[myArray count]`. My usual mistake is:

```
for (int i = 0; i < [myArray count] - 1; i++) {
```

If the array is empty, this loop executes basically forever because `[myArray count]-1` overflows the `unsigned int`.

I do use fast enumeration where possible, but in this project I very often need to refer the objects at indexes `i-1` and `i+1` while processing object `i` and it doesn't seem to lend itself to that. Any other tips for avoiding these bugs, other than just being less incompetent?

Comment: accessing objects within an array at indices below zero will lead to crashes. so, simplest thing is to take care when writing for loops is the best thing to do.

Comment: Hmm, I wonder why the relevant compiler warnings are switched off. I didn't knowingly change anything from the defaults. iOS_Pradip below reckons it's something new in Xcode.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, there's a warning you can turn on to pick up these issues.  I think it's "sign comparison", the command line flag is `-Wsign-compare`.

If you want to iterate over the elements of an array but you need the index, the neatest way (in my opinion) is [-enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000137-SW19)

```
[myArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock: ^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) 
{
    NSlog(@"Object at index %lu is %@", (unsigned long) idx, obj);
    if (idx > 0)
    {
        NSlog(@"Previous object is %@", [myArray objectAtIndex: idx - 1]);
    }
    if (idx + 1 < [myArray count])
    {
        NSlog(@"Next object is %@", [myArray objectAtIndex: idx + 1]);
    }
}];
```

Comment: Also notice the matching type. If you're iterating over a number your counter should be the same type. It isn't required but it gives you everything that you might get.

Answer (score 2):

You can still using the index while doing fast enumeration, just do:

```
for (id object in myArray)
{
    NSInteger anIndex=[myArray indexOfObject:object];
}
```

Comment: That would make the code a lot neater. I wonder how fast that `indexOfObject` call is though? I guess it must search through the entire array sequentially.

Comment: i guess it can be quite slow

Comment: Yes, it can be slow, but given your huge array it may be the only solution unless you try to redesign your program to fit smaller arrays

Comment: Instead of calling indexOfObject: you can use a counter.

Comment: That turns an O(n) loop into an O(n^2) loop.

Comment: `indexOfObject:` returns the index of the *first* matching object, so you have problems if the array contains "equal" objects.

Answer (score 0):

As per my suggestion, 
You can go with Antonio MG answer

And you want loop then try the below code

```
   int totalObj = myArray.count-1;
for (int i = 0; i<totalObj; i++) {
    // Write your code
}
```

Comment: Its a new Xcode issue.
Apple changed some compilation flag, I don't know how this happening.

Answer (score -1):

JeremyP's answer is the best.  If for some reason you don't want to use fast enumeration to run though the for loop, one suggestion is to just learn to use unsigned integers for your indices.

```
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < something.count; i++) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure that would help with either of the examples given.