# 1 < -1 evaluates to TRUE

Tags: ios, objective-c

In part of my code I was writing a simple `for` loop to iterate over elements in an array (all `NSMutableDictionary`s), and I found out the loop executed even if the condition was basically 1 < -1.

So I wrote the following code, to test the validity of this issue:

```
NSMutableArray* arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

NSLog(@"COUNT: %d | %i", arr.count, 1 < (arr.count - 1));
```

The output was:

```
COUNT: 0 | 1
```

Which essentially means the count is 0, and that 1 is less than -1.

I thought maybe it's because the array is freshly initialized, and maybe adding and removing an object might change this a bit so I went on to do this:

```
NSMutableArray* arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

[arr addObject:@1];
[arr removeObject:@1];

NSLog(@"COUNT: %d | %i", arr.count, 1 < (arr.count - 1));
```

Still same result:

```
COUNT: 0 | 1
```

The possible reasons that come to my mind for this:

- There is something about the compiler/objective-C that I do not understand yet
- Registers in my Mac are haunted
- I'm losing my mind

I highly doubt that it's either of the last 2 cases, still I'd like to know **why** this is happening.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`arr.count` is an unsigned integer value (of type `NSUInteger`). With unsigned arithmetic, `(0 - 1)` wraps around to a very large positive number, not `-1`.

You may see the results you expect if you cast the values to signed integers:

```
NSLog(@"COUNT: %d | %i", (int)arr.count, 1 < ((int)arr.count - 1));
```

See this topic for some ways to deal with this common source of bugs: [Constant bugs from [NSArray count] being unsigned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21479201/constant-bugs-from-nsarray-count-being-unsigned)

Answer (score 4):

The reason why this happens is that `1` on the left is treated as *unsigned*. In turn, this happens because `arr.count` is of unsigned type, making the expression `arr.count-1` unsigned as well. When you subtract `1` from an unsigned zero, you get an underflow, and the result is a very large *positive* number.

To avoid problems like this, be extremely careful with subtraction when dealing with values of `unsigned` types. Prefer addition to the other side - specifically, rather than writing

```
if (a < unsignedB - c)
```

write

```
if (a+c < unsignedB)
```

Answer (score 3):

The `count` property of arrays is of `NSUInteger` type, which means `unsigned long`. The expression `arr.count - 1` is subtracting 1 from unsigned integer, so the result is unsigned as well. Instead of -1 you get very large positive number because of overflow, and this number is greater than 1.

Answer (score 2):

the `[arr count]` returns `(NSUInteger)` which is nothing but `typedef unsigned long NSUInteger;`

So there won't be any negative numbers for `NSUInteger`. The values start from 0 to some max value and it will be like a loop as follows

```
... | MAX-2 | MAX-1 | MAX | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | ...
           -1      -1    -1  -1  -1  -1  -1

So, the math is like 2-1 = 1
                     1-1 = 0
                     0-1 = MAX
                     0-2 = MAX-1
```

Comment: I like how you explained this, but is the information you have aligned right?